# Sendind data as string from C# to Javascript - how to check String?

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to send some date from C# to Javascript. Data - it's code of html. But when I send it to Javascript it fail. When I put "ideal data" it works.

Than I'm quite sure that error is inside text contain HTML code.

I do it:

```
data = data.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
data = data.Replace("\n", "\\\n");
data = data.Replace("\t", " ");
```

But this still not help. Do you know any library to check that string is ok for client JS?
Or What I should do to check string?

**EDIT:**

Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Data which I try put (example):

Poczta - Najlepsza Poczta, największe załączniki - WP.PL                                                                                                       -->                                                -->                                                                                                              logowanie                                       Poczta |                TopNews |               WP.PL na komórkę |                Nokaut.pl                       WP.homepagelink()                                                           //                                                               Logowanie do poczty WP                  Logowanie dla Twojego bezpieczeństwa jest szyfrowane (SSL)                                                                                                                                                              Login lub adres e-mail:                                                                                         WP.$('#login').focus();                                                                                                         Hasło:                                                                                                                                                                      poczta mini                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Nie mogę się zalogować! »                                                                                                                                                                     Nie masz konta?                                                     Załóż je »                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Skuteczny antyspam                                          więcej..                                                                                                        Pojemność bez limitów                                           więcej..                                                                                                        Poczta w komórce                                            więcej..                                                                                                        Duże załączniki                                         więcej..                                                                                        NPB("006");                                Polecane:                       Pogoda              |               Wyznaczanie trasy               |               BMI                 |               Tarot               |               Program tv              |               Plotki              |               Moje IP                 |               Wiadomości                 |               Sport               |               Top News                                                            O firmie|               Dla prasy|              Reklama|                Biznes z WP.PL|                 Skontaktuj się z WP.PL|                Praca|              Prywatność|               Zasady korzystania|                 Polityka antyspamowa                                        Zobacz wszystkie serwisy|               RSS                         Copyright © 1995-2012 Wirtualna Polska

Comment: What data fails? What errors/exceptions are you getting? _How_ are you sending the data?

Comment: In which format are you sending data which failed and what is the input string you sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET4 there's a new [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx) method. For earlier versions have a look here:  [Embedding JavaScript Strings from an ASP.NET Page](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jul/14/Embedding-JavaScript-Strings-from-an-ASPNET-Page)

Answer (score 1):

Using this object we serialize and deserialize  objects in C#. Here is a quick sample:

A simple Employee object:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }   
}
```

Adding some instances of them to a List:

```
Employee oEmployee1 = 
       new Employee{Name="Pini",ID="111", Age="30"};

Employee oEmployee2 = 
      new Employee { Name = "Yaniv", ID = "Cohen", Age = "31" };
Employee oEmployee3 = 
        new Employee { Name = "Yoni", ID = "Biton", Age = "20" };

List<Employee> oList = new List<Employee>() 
{ oEmployee1, oEmployee2, oEmployee3 };

Serializing then:

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
         new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(oList);
And here is the output:

[{"Name":"Pini","Age":"30","ID":"111"},
{"Name":"Yaniv","Age":"31","ID":"Cohen"},
{"Name":"Yoni","Age":"20","ID":"Biton"}]
```